# why the Nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This is the scenario:

```
class A{
int a;
}

class B{
A objectA[]=new A[10] ;
}

class C{
B ObjectB;
public static void main(String[] args){
ObjectB.ObjectA[0].a=1;
}
}
```

I get a nullpointerexception in main operation. However if I declare just one object of class A, I don't get the error. Why so? How do I rectify it?

Comment: `new A[10]` doesn't actually *create* 10 `A`s.

Comment: isn't your ObjectB null?

Comment: @bzlm- Ok, I get it. But if I replace it with A objecta=new A() , it works fine. How is that possible?

Comment: @PRamesh, that was exactly my point. :)

Comment: @peshkira- Sorry, it must've been B ObjectB=new ObjectB();

Comment: @bzlm- SO initialising all the object's values in a constructor should work fine? *I'm trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `new B()` initializes an array of objects of type `A`, but none of the member objects.  You can rectify it first initializing `objectB` and then calling `objectA[i] = new A()` for each item in the array.

```
class B{
    A objectA[]=new A[10] ;
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            objectA[i] = new A();
    }
}

class C{
B ObjectB = new B();
public static void main(String[] args){
ObjectB.ObjectA[0].a=1;
}
}
```

Comment: Not true. Though he will need to do it, the NPE is caused by trying to access `ObjectA[]`, in `ObjectB`, which is null.

Comment: @PRamesh edited my answer, this should give you a correct example.

Answer (score 5):

(1) `B ObjectB;` does not create a new instance of `B`, it just crate the variable, to crate an instance; `B ObjectB = new B();`

(2) Also `A objectA[]=new A[10] ;` allocates the array, but not elements in the array, and `ObjectB.ObjectA[0].a=1;` will also cause NPE.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the ObjectB. There is no memory allocated to ObjectB. Hence showing null pointer exception (Nothing is allocated to ObjectB reference).

This should work:

class C {
    B ObjectB = new B();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectB.ObjectA[0].a = 1;
}
```

}